# R package monitoR error on dbUploadTemplate [pkg-monitor]

Tags: mysql, r

I'm using the R package [monitoR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/monitoR/index.html) and getting an error message that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to upload a correlation template list ("bithTemps") to a MySQL database ("noh") using the dbUploadTemplate command.

```
dbUploadTemplate(templates = bithTemps,
             uid = "root",
             pwd = "****",
             db.name = "noh",
             analyst = 1, 
             locationID = "2",
             date.recorded = "2017/09/07",
             recording.equip = "Unknown",
             species.code = "BITH",
             type = "COR")
```

This returns:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I have confirmed the ODBC connection is working, that the template list is functional (i.e., it works when called to other arguments in the package), and that the SQL database has the required entries for analyst, location, and species code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this error was actually triggered by a non-functional ODBC connection. This part of the dbUploadTemplate function

```
  species <- RODBC::sqlQuery(dbCon, paste("SELECT `pkSpeciesID`, `fldSpeciesCode` FROM `tblSpecies` WHERE `fldSpeciesCode` = '", 
        paste(species.code, sep = "", collapse = "' OR `fldSpeciesCode` = '"), 
        "'", sep = ""))
```

queries a table in the SQL database and returns an object called 'species'. If the query fails (e.g., because RODBC can't connect) than 'species' is empty, and the following operation

```
        speciesID <- NULL    
for (i in 1:length(species.code)) {
    speciesID[i] <- species$pkSpeciesID[species$fldSpeciesCode == 
        species.code[i]]
}
```

triggers the error. Fixing the ODBC connection resolves the error.